# Azure CI/CD pipeline for Synapse Artifacts Deployment on multiple environments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

**Background -**
As per our dev team, they wanted a CI/CD pipeline for deployment of Synapse artifacts - Notebooks, Scripts, Pipelines. I'm creating a Release pipeline in Azure DevOps. But there is an issue for dependent resources like SQL pools, Spark pools etc. Dev team has created separate sparkppols, sqlpools on each environments with different names.

**Issue -**
I'm creating a single pipeline to deploy the Synapse artifacts (pipelines, scripts, notebooks) whenever they are going to change or newly gets added. I'm using Synapse workspace deployment task for deployment which creates and uses ARM templates in the backend. But how we can automate the process to deploy the same artifacts on different environments with different reference objects like sparkpool, sqlpool (On DEV - sqlpooldev, sparkppoldev. On TEST - sqlpooltest, sparkppoltest etc.)

I tried custom template (template-parameters-definition.json) on collaboration branch, but it creates parameters for all objects separately like <pipeline_name>_poolname,_sparkpoolreferencename etc. So if new object gets added, then we have to add the ARM template parameters everytime.

So what is the best way/practice to automate these scenarios with single pipeline ?

Comment: Have you tried to `OverrideParameters` on the Synapse workspace deployment task?sample link [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/data-architecture-blog/ci-cd-in-azure-synapse-analytics-part-4-the-release-pipeline/ba-p/2034434)?

Comment: In my case, for each for the notebook (or artifact), it's created a parameter. Even if I added override parameters for each of them then if developer adds new artifact then I have to again add parameter for it in  the pipeline manually.

Comment: If the artifact is dynamic, i'm afraid there's no out-of-box feature for the pipeline.  One possible way is to get the parameter change in previous job or steps and update the template file.